# View Controller not showing Data from TableViewController

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, indexing, didselectrowatindexpath

I created a TableViewController that loads the data for the cells from an Array. (Works fine beside the speed of it loading, any tips on that?)

My problem is I also created a View Controller with buttons connected to it. I want the buttons to load the data based off of what cell was selected in the previous view.

I watched a couple videos on YouTube that all show that same method of handling this but it's not working when I attempt to use this theory in my code.

Here is the original TableViewController code

```swift
//  CatagoryTableViewController.swift

import UIKit

var list = [Categories]()

var myIndex = 0

class CatagoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "In The Mix", choiceA: "Ivy Smith", choiceB: "Shay West", choiceC: "Donald Allen", choiceD: "Zay (Wooo)"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Male Organization",choiceA: "People Standing United", choiceB: "Young Kings Movement", choiceC: "Gentlemen Qualities", choiceD: "" ))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Female Organization", choiceA: "RSVP", choiceB: "STARS", choiceC: "NCNW", choiceD: "BSLS"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Dancer", choiceA: "Ansord Rashied", choiceB: "Donald Allen", choiceC: "Isis Ferguson", choiceD: "Jada Mosoey"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Most Likely To Brighten Your Day", choiceA: "Bar'rae Choice", choiceB: "Tytiana Jackson", choiceC: "Ivery Tanner", choiceD: "Chinonye Agu"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Modeling Troop", choiceA: "Ziana Fashion Club", choiceB: "We R 1 Family", choiceC: "", choiceD: ""))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Male Friend Group", choiceA: "Quincy, Kraig, and Kiefer", choiceB: "WOOO", choiceC: "Kevin, Ivery, Kendell, and Marc", choiceD: "Dre, Eli, Jafari, and Ryan"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Female Friend Group", choiceA: "Omolara, Xela, Reggie, and Shania", choiceB: "Dior, Ashleigh, Tanya, Asha, Jazamine, and Aliea", choiceC: "Damo, Dani, Ty,Tati, and Ivy", choiceD: "Ahmani, Leshay, and Nyia"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Dressed Male", choiceA: "Dane Tyree", choiceB: "Ajamu Davis", choiceC: "Taj Green", choiceD: "Isiah Thomas"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Dressed Female", choiceA: "Imani Stamford", choiceB: "Ivy Smith", choiceC: "Tyler Murray", choiceD: "Kam"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best DJ", choiceA: "Dj Topchoice", choiceB: "Dj Mizzy", choiceC: "Dj Che", choiceD: ""))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Clothing Line", choiceA: "Visonary Society", choiceB: "Rare World", choiceC: "Handwritten", choiceD: "Soigne Y Pree"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Clothing Line", choiceA: "2016", choiceB: "2015", choiceC: "2014", choiceD: "2013"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Miss Lincoln", choiceA: "2016", choiceB: "2015", choiceC: "2014", choiceD: "2013"))
        list.append(Categories(categoryText: "Best Mr Lincoln", choiceA: "2016", choiceB: "2015", choiceC: "2014", choiceD: "2013"))
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      let count = list.count
            return count
        }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)

     let category = list[indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel?.text = category.categoryName
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        myIndex = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNominees", sender: self)

    }
}
```

Here if the View Controller that should show the data based off the cell that was selected. I HAVE NO ERRORS BUT THE BUTTONS STILL SAY BUTTONS WHEN THE PROGRAM IS RUNNING.

```html
//  ViewController.swift
  
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var optionA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionC: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionD: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nominees = list[myIndex]
        print(nominees)
        optionA.titleLabel?.text = nominees.optionA
        optionB.titleLabel?.text = nominees.optionB
        optionC.titleLabel?.text = nominees.optionC
        optionD.titleLabel?.text = nominees.optionD
    }
}
 */
```

Comment: Declaring the data source array as global variable outside of the class is very bad habit. **Don't do that**. Pass the data between the controllers in the segue or use a singleton class.

Comment: @vadian is correct. You should also use `setTitle("your string", for: .normal)` when trying to set the text on button's label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly declare your list variable inside Your tableViewController. Add this :

```
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNominees", sender: indexPath)
```

Create nominees variable outside of viewDidLoad method, but inside Your second viewController.
Use prepare for segue method :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "showNominees" {
               if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController {
                    guard let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }
                    vc.nominees = self.list[indexPath.row]
                  }            
            }
        }
```

And guys have already mentioned that You should use setTitle :

```
self.optionA.setTitle(nominees.choiceA, for: .normal)
```

It should work now.Hopefully.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi where exactly should I put the first line of code you stated. "self.peformSegie" ?

Comment: in the same place You have. In didselect row method. Just replace one with another.

Comment: Hi thanks. I think my last question is where do you put the self.optionA.setTitle(nominees.choiceA, for: .normal) . I also created the variable nominees like the following "var nominees = "" ". Is that the correct syntax?

Comment: in next view controller in place of «optionA.titleLabel?.text = nominees.optionA

Comment: And no, @Dash, var nominees = "" is not a correct way to define variable. You should remember that list[indexpath.row] has the Categories type. if you want to initialise empty var, You need to declare it like this : var nominees = Categories(categoryText: "", choiceA: "", choiceB: "", choiceC: "", choiceD: "")

Comment: My button labels are not showing up after I setTitle but before I set them the default button label would show. I put a print statement next to the return in the prepare segue just to see what was happening and it returns my text. Should it be returning anything? I can see that the tableviewcontroller nominee is picking up the choiceA, choiceB but not the other ViewController

Comment: I got it to work. Had to the guard statement to the following "guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }". Thanks for your help !